# Button seems to be covered by video

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I am trying to write a program that captures photos with webcam. I want to add a JButton to the JFrame of a live video. Yet, the button doesnt show up. My belief is that it is covered by the video. I attached my code below.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
private JPanel contentPane;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
    frame.contentPane.add(new JButton("Camera"));
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
 // Create the frame.
public MyFrame() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 650, 490);      
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    new MyThread().start();
}
VideoCap videoCap = new VideoCap();
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g = contentPane.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(videoCap.getOneFrame(), 0, 0, this);
}
class MyThread extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (;;){
            repaint();
            try { Thread.sleep(30);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {    }
        }  
    } 
}
}
```

Any suggestions would be awesome.
I looked through many questions regarding Jbuttons not showing up, but I am not sure which one is similar to mine. Please point me in the right direction if there is.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `MyFrame frame = new MyFrame(); frame.setVisible(true);` Add all components and `pack()` the frame before displaying it. Other tips: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: Firstly add all components to `JFrame` and then set it's visible property to `true`. Secondly, inside `MyFrame` constructor, you are setting the `contentPane` for the said `JFrame`, though this reference of `contentPane` is completely ignored in the `main` method. Don't use inheritance if you have no idea what is going on? Lastly, in `main', you used a `JPanel` with default layout, and adding `JButton` to it with `BorderLayout` constraints!! That surprises me most :(

Comment: `public void paint(Graphics g){
    g = contentPane.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(videoCap.getOneFrame(), 0, 0, this);
}` Wow.. that's messed up in a number of ways. 1) Don't call `getGraphics` (except on a `BufferedImage`) 2) A panel is added on top of the frame, so any custom painting in the frame will not be visible. 3) It's better to override `paintComponent(Graphics)` in a `JComponent` (like `JPanel`) than in a top level container like `JFrame` (that is not double buffered) ..

Comment: BTW - `JPanel panel = new JPanel(); ..   panel.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);` A `JPanel` by default has a `FlowLayout`. The above code suggests you are 'coding by magic' - just tossing together a random group of code lines hoping that logic will emerge by accident. Tip: **It won't.**

Comment: @AndrewThompson I appreciate your recommendations about question format and made the necessary edits. Let me take some time to digest your suggestions!!!

Comment: @nIcEcOw  Thanks for the corrections, I think I made the changes you recommended.

Comment: I apologize if I am asking stupid questions, I just started to learn how to code last semester and been trying to try new stuff this summer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure, as to which library you are using in order to create the said video. Though in this example, I used the `opencv` library to create an image from webcam. You have to modify it, in order to make it work for your usecase.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.opencv.core.*;     
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;

public class ApplicationBase {

    private BufferedImage m_Captured_BufferedImage;

    static {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        System.loadLibrary ( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
    }

    private void displayGUI ( BufferedImage image, String title, int x, int y ) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ( title );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel ( new BorderLayout ( 5, 5 ) );

        PictureDrawer pictureDrawer = new PictureDrawer ( image );
        contentPane.add ( pictureDrawer, BorderLayout.CENTER );

        JButton button = new JButton ( "Click Me not!" );
        contentPane.add ( button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END );

        frame.setContentPane ( contentPane );
        frame.pack ();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform ( true );
        frame.setVisible ( true );
    }

    private void startApp () {
        VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture ( 0 );

        Mat videoFrame = new Mat ();
        camera.read ( videoFrame );

        if ( camera.read ( videoFrame ) ) {
            m_Captured_BufferedImage = matToBufferedImage ( videoFrame );
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable () {
                @Override
                public void run () {
                    displayGUI ( m_Captured_BufferedImage, "Image", 0, 0 );
                }
            };                  
            EventQueue.invokeLater ( runnable );
        }
        camera.release ();
    }

    public BufferedImage matToBufferedImage ( Mat videoFrame ) {
        //Mat() to BufferedImage
        int type = 0;
        if ( videoFrame.channels () == 1 ) {
            type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
        } else if ( videoFrame.channels () == 3 ) {
            type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
        }
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage ( videoFrame.width (), videoFrame.height (), type );
        WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster ();
        DataBufferByte dataBuffer = ( DataBufferByte ) raster.getDataBuffer ();
        byte [] data = dataBuffer.getData ();
        videoFrame.get ( 0, 0, data );

        return image;
    }

    public static void main ( String [] args ) {
        new ApplicationBase ().startApp ();
    }
}

class PictureDrawer extends JComponent {

    private BufferedImage m_BufferedImage;

    public PictureDrawer ( BufferedImage bufferedImage ) {
        this.m_BufferedImage = bufferedImage;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent ( Graphics g ) {
        super.paintComponent ( g );
        g.drawImage ( m_BufferedImage, 0, 0, this );
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize () {
        return new Dimension ( m_BufferedImage.getWidth (), m_BufferedImage.getHeight () );
    }
}
```

I downloaded the OpenCV library from [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/)

Compiled the project with this command:

```
javac -classpath .;C:\install\opencv\opencv\build\java\opencv-320.jar; -d bin source\*.java
```

Command to run project:

```
>java -classpath .;C:\install\opencv\opencv\build\java\opencv-320.jar; -Djava.library.path=C:\install\opencv\opencv\build\java\x64 ApplicationBase
```

Comment: Thank you, your program takes a screenshot right after I press run. Is it because I am suppose to run it through the window command prompt?

Comment: @HanWang: No actually this program is meant to use webcame to take a single snap. It is just an example to let you know, how to place components, instead of dwelling deep into functionality :-)

Comment: I see, I'll go on from there. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @HanWang: You're MOST WELCOME, and KEEP SMILING :-)

Answer (score 3):

You are adding button to content pane and then drawing the video on it. Of course video will overlay your button.

Some suggestions:

1. Don't set custom content pane.
2. Create two separate panels and add them to content pane.
3. Add button to one panel.
4. Draw your video onto another.
5. Refactor your code to properly override `paintComponent` and redraw it from another thread.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! How do I properly refactor my code to override paintComponent?

Comment: See this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123633/image-drawing-with-paintcomponent-java

Comment: so a frame by default has a content pane?

Comment: Yes, and usually you dont want to replace it.

Comment: If possible. Can you please provide an example of putting the live video into a panel? I am lost at what to do. Thank you!